# Merging worksheets from multiple excel worksheets with different headers and header row numbers

Tags: excel, vba, merge

Hello I am trying to combine multiple worksheets (15) from different sources into a single excel sheet with standardized headers. The difficult part is:

1. Each worksheet may have a different header name for the same variable across worksheets
2. The starting row for the header is different in each worksheet
3. An identifier of the data tab source needs to be added for each row brought in from that worksheet

I have created a key which I planned to try to use for a loop. The Key contains the "final header" and for each example sheet, contains under the final header what the specific tab header is called. In addition, it also includes the header start row number.

[image: Header Key for each tab and header row number]

I am very new to VBA and honestly am struggling to even start on this so would greatly appreciate any support which can be provided.

Comment: You could use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` to find the header in each row in question.

Answer (score 0):

### Create Summary Using Key

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub createSummary()
    
    Const kName As String = "KeySheet"
    Const kFirst As String = "A1"
    Const rName As String = "Summary"
    Const rFirst As String = "A1"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Write values from Key Range to Key Data array.
    With wb.Worksheets(kName)
        Dim kData As Variant ' Key Data
        kData = getRange(defineRangeUsingFirstCell(.Range(kFirst)))
    End With
    
    ' Write values from worksheet ranges to Worksheet Data array.
    Dim kRows As Long
    kRows = UBound(kData, 1)
    Dim wsData As Variant ' Worksheets Data
    ReDim wsData(1 To kRows)
    Dim tRows As Long
    tRows = 1 ' for header
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To kRows
        wsData(i) = getRange(defineRangeUsingFirstCell( _
            wb.Worksheets(kData(i, 1)).Cells(kData(i, 2), 1)))
        tRows = tRows + UBound(wsData(i), 1) - 1
    Next i
    Dim kCols As Long
    kCols = UBound(kData, 2)
    
    ' Define Result Data array.
    Dim rData As Variant ' Result Data
    ReDim rData(1 To tRows, 1 To kCols)
    
    Dim hData As Variant ' Header Data
    Dim CurrCol As Variant
    Dim wsRows As Long
    Dim CurrRow As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim l As Long
    Dim m As Long
    
    ' Write headers.
    For j = 1 To kCols
        rData(1, j) = kData(1, j)
    Next j
    ' Write body.
    CurrRow = 1
    For i = 2 To kRows
        ReDim hData(1 To UBound(wsData(i), 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(wsData(i), 2)
            hData(j) = wsData(i)(1, j)
        Next j
        wsRows = UBound(wsData(i), 1)
        For l = 1 To 2
            For k = 2 To wsRows
                rData(CurrRow + k - 1, l) = kData(i, l)
            Next k
        Next l
        For l = 3 To kCols
            CurrCol = Application.Match(kData(i, l), hData, 0)
            For k = 2 To wsRows
                rData(CurrRow + k - 1, l) = wsData(i)(k, CurrCol)
            Next k
        Next l
        CurrRow = CurrRow + wsRows - 1
    Next i
        
    ' Write values from Result Data array to Result Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(rName).Range(rFirst).Resize(, kCols)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(tRows).Value = rData
    End With

End Sub

Function defineRangeUsingFirstCell(FirstCell As Range) As Range
    On Error GoTo clearError
    With FirstCell
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
            .Worksheet.Columns.Count - .Column + 1)
    End With
    With rng
        Dim cel As Range
        Set cel = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        Set cel = .Worksheet.Cells(cel.Row, .Find(What:="*", _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column)
        Set defineRangeUsingFirstCell = .Resize( _
            cel.Row - .Row + 1, cel.Column - .Column + 1)
    End With
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function getRange(rng As Range) As Variant
    On Error GoTo clearError
    With rng
        Dim Data As Variant
        If .Rows.Count > 1 Or .Columns.Count > 1 Then
            Data = .Value
        Else
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = .Value
        End If
    End With
    getRange = Data
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I am getting a run-time error within the section :

Comment: Thanks for the code! I am getting a run-time error within the "Write body" section specifically in the rData loop, 
            For k = 2 To wsRows
                rData(CurrRow + k - 1, l) = kData(i, l)
            Next k     'kData = Sheet1 at this point and CurrRow=1; k=11. rData=<subscript out of range> and hData = <subscript out of range>. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. A few rows above change `tRows = tRows + UBound(wsData(i), 1) - 1`.